# Как получить рандомное значение ключа из словаря?

Tags: python, случайные-числа

Хотелось бы использовать модуль random

Comment: А обратиться к документации?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4859292/how-to-get-a-random-value-from-dictionary-in-python

Comment: Нужно получить ключ, или значение по ключу, или ключ и значение?

Answer (score 2):

Можно с преобразованием ключей словаря в список. Готового метода нет.

```
from random import choice    

a = {1: 101, 2: 102, 3: 103}
print(choice(list(a.keys())))
```

или в последней строке просто

```
print(choice(list(a)))
```

Так как словарь итерируется по ключам.

Если нужно получить рандомное значение словаря, то соотвествтенно

```
print(choice(list(a.values())))
```

Если словарь вида

```
a = {1: [101, 102]}
```

и нужно получить рандомное значение по ключу:

```
print(choice(a.get(1)))
```

Comment: `print(choice(list(a.items())))` а так получим кортеж `(ключ, значение)`.